# AngularJS on-click not working when i'm passing it an ID

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I receive the following error

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'edition.multiverse_id' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 17 of the expression [AddCardToList({{edition.multiverse_id}})] starting at [edition.multiverse_id}})].
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$parse/syntax?p0=edition.multiverse_id&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=17&p3=AddCardToList(%7B%7Bedition.multiverse_id%7D%7D)&p4=edition.multiverse_id%7D%7D)

with the following html

```
 <button type="button" ng-if="$index == 0" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-href='#' ng-click="AddCardToList({{edition.multiverse_id}})">{{edition.multiverse_id}}</button>
```

the buttons are nicely wrapped in a repeater that's inside a div element that has the following

```
<li ng-repeat="edition in card.editions" >
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

The following angular code I'm trying to have my button be the click event to is the following

```
 $scope.AddCardToList = function (multiverse_id) {
        $http.get("https://api.deckbrew.com/mtg/cards?multiverseid=" + multiverse_id).then(onCardListAddComplete, onError);
    };
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  And a thorough explanation why this won't work will help me become a better AngularJS programmer.  Much appreciated in advance.

Comment: `ng-click="AddCardToList(edition.multiverse_id)"`. Since you're calling a function without curly brackets (`AddCardToList`), why would you use them for a variable (`edition.multiverse_id`)?

Comment: don't wrap function arguments in `{{}}` . Digest is expecting the actual param either as a string value or scope variable

Comment: I can just pass in the object right?  Might as well just pass in the object then, good point!

Thanks! make that an answer and I'll up the vote!

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Why all the down votes? The question is clear and has the offending code and not too much extra stuff. Seems like a fine question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use braces anywhere inside `ng-click`

```
<button type="button" ng-if="$index == 0" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-href='#' ng-click="AddCardToList(edition.multiverse_id)">{{edition.multiverse_id}}</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces are for inserting scope variables or expressions into an area that expects text.  The [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive evaluates it's contents as an [angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) on the current scope, which is similar to javascript expressions in general, see the link for information.

So if you have some html that is expecting a string such as a `class` attribute you can use the double brackets, but if you're using a directive such as [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) that expects an expression you should not:

```
<span class="{{className}}">This will set the css class to `$scope.className`</span>
<span ng-class="{ className: true }">This will do the same thing</span>
```